# How to add up values of radio buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm a newbie coder and cannot for the life of me figure out how to add up values for radio buttons below - any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying to create a diabetes screening assessment tool - where you will be able to assign different values to different risk factors.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: your labels correctly use the `for` attribute, but none of your `<input>`'s use the correct ID!

Comment: If the `fma.js` file shows your current work, please post the code in your question.

Comment: @Sidney - when a user selects the radio buttons I want to add up the corresponding selected values using javascript. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the <input> and correct ids can you explain? Many thanks!

Comment: @Sébastien - I can't get any JS code to work and add up the values, initially I was trying something along the lines of assigning functions to the names and then using getElementById.value to try and add up the values but that wasn't working out so well..

Comment: Regarding the `for` attribute and `id`'s, each `<label>` should be `for` one `<input>`. The `for` attribute should be set to the `<input>`'s ID.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use JavaScript to accomplish this.

Here's one way to do it:

- Listen for the form's `submit` event
- Prevent the default (so that the form doesn't get sent to the server)
- Grab the value from each field. Fields use the `name` attribute from the HTML
- Use `parseInt` on each field because they'll be strings
- Add them up
- Display the result (in this example, in the console)

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const total =
    parseInt(form.age.value) +
    parseInt(form.bmi.value) +
    parseInt(form.famhistory.value) +
    parseInt(form.diet.value)
  console.log(total)
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Zedland Health Authority's Diabetes health assessment tool</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fma.css">
  <script src="fma.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="pageheading">Zedland Health Authority's Diabetes health assessment tool</h1>
  <form id="register">
    <fieldset id="controls">
      <div>
        <label class="button" for="Age">How old are you?</label>
        <input type="radio" id="agerange" name="age" value="0" checked="checked">
        <label for="agerange1">1-25</label>
        <input type="radio" id="agerange" name="age" value="5">
        <label for="agerange2">26-40</label>
        <input type="radio" id="agerange" name="age" value="8">
        <label for="agerange3">40-60</label>
        <input type="radio" id="agerange" name="age" value="10">
        <label for="agerange4">60+</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="button" for="bmi">What is your BMI?</label>
        <input type="radio" id="bmi" name="bmi" value="0" checked="checked">
        <label for="bmi1">0-25</label>
        <input type="radio" id="bmi" name="bmi" value="0">
        <label for="bmi2">26-30</label>
        <input type="radio" id="bmi" name="bmi" value="9">
        <label for="bmi3">31-35</label>
        <input type="radio" id="bmi" name="bmi" value="10">
        <label for="bmi4">35+</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="button" for="famhistory">Does anybody in your family have diabetes?</label>
        <input type="radio" id="famhistory" name="famhistory" value="0" checked="checked">
        <label for="famhistory1">No</label>
        <input type="radio" id="famhistory" name="famhistory" value="7">
        <label for="famhistory2">Grandparent</label>
        <input type="radio" id="famhistory" name="famhistory" <label for="famhistory3">Sibling</label>
        <input type="radio" id="famhistory" name="famhistory" value="15">
        <label for="famhistory4">Parent</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="button" for="diet">How would you describe your diet?</label>
        <input type="radio" id="diet" name="diet" value="0" checked="checked">
        <label for="diet1">Low sugar</label>
        <input type="radio" id="diet" name="diet" value="7">
        <label for="diet2">Normal sugar</label>
        <input type="radio" id="diet" name="diet" value="15">
        <label for="diet3">Quite high sugar</label>
        <input type="radio" id="diet" name="diet" value="15">
        <label for="diet4">High sugar</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
    </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works well, however I noticed an error in the original HTML: bmi has value 0 **twice** which leads to incorrect outcome I assume.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on adding values, here is a more flexible approach.

The idea is to loop through each relevant input (those that are inside your fieldset with ID `controls`), regardless of its name, so that if you add more checks, the same code will still work.

Create a `score` variable and increment it with the value of each input that is checked.

**Be careful, you have the value 0 *TWICE* for the BMI check**

```js
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var form = document.querySelector('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#controls input');
        var score = 0;
        inputs.forEach(function(input) {
            if (input.checked) {
                score += parseInt(input.value, 10);
            }

        });
        console.log(score);
    });

  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zedland Health Authority's Diabetes health assessment tool</title>
    <script>



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="pageheading">Zedland Health Authority's Diabetes health assessment tool</h1>
    <form id="register">
    <fieldset id="controls">
        <div>
          <label class="button" for="Age">How old are you?</label>
            <input type="radio" id="agerange" name="age" value="0" checked="checked">

            <label for="agerange1">1-25</label>
            <input type="radio" id="agerange" name="age" value="5">
            <label for="agerange2">26-40</label>
            <input type="radio" id="agerange" name="age" value="8">
            <label for="agerange3">40-60</label>
            <input type="radio" id="agerange" name="age" value="10">
            <label for="agerange4">60+</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="button" for="bmi">What is your BMI?</label>
            <input type="radio" id="bmi" name="bmi" value="0" checked="checked">

            <label for="bmi1">0-25</label>
            <input type="radio" id="bmi" name="bmi"  value="0">
            <label for="bmi2">26-30</label>
            <input type="radio" id="bmi" name="bmi" value="9">
            <label for="bmi3">31-35</label>
            <input type="radio" id="bmi" name="bmi"  value="10">
            <label for="bmi4">35+</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="button" for="famhistory">Does anybody in your family have diabetes?</label>
            <input type="radio" id="famhistory" name="famhistory" value="0" checked="checked">
            <label for="famhistory1">No</label>
            <input type="radio" id="famhistory" name="famhistory" value="7">
            <label for="famhistory2">Grandparent</label>
            <input type="radio" id="famhistory" name="famhistory"
            <label for="famhistory3">Sibling</label>
            <input type="radio" id="famhistory" name="famhistory" value="15">
            <label for="famhistory4">Parent</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="button" for="diet">How would you describe your diet?</label>
            <input type="radio" id="diet" name="diet"  value="0" checked="checked">
            <label for="diet1">Low sugar</label>
            <input type="radio" id="diet" name="diet"  value="7">
            <label for="diet2">Normal sugar</label>
            <input type="radio" id="diet" name="diet" value="15">
            <label for="diet3">Quite high sugar</label>
            <input type="radio" id="diet" name="diet" value="15">
            <label for="diet4">High sugar</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
  <div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code works when i run it on here, but not on brackets - which is what i'm using to code off of - any ideas why?! Thanks a lot for the above.

Comment: You need to put the JavaScript code either inside the `<script>` tag, or in your external JS file.